# Criando um retorno linq com uma sublista

Tags: c#, linq

Estou tentando escrever uma query em linq para resolver o seguinte problema:

Eu tenho uma Lista Alunos que tenho os dados dos alunos como Id, Nome, Matricula, cpf...

Em outra entidade tenho as notas onde esta o AlunoId, MateriaId, Nota...

quero um retorno onde a entidade retorne:

Nome,
Matricula,
Cpf,
**Notas**  <- Lista de notas

E que consiga fazer filtros no conjunto como retornar os alunos que tiveram notas abaixo de 7.

No entity montei

```cs
var query = contexto.Aluno
            .Include(i => i.Notas)
            .Select( s => new { s.Nome, s.Matricula, s.Cpf, s.Notas})
            .AsQueryable();

// O que estou tentando fazer algo como:
**query = query.Where(q => q.Notas.Where(qq => qq.Nota < 7))**
```

Se eu trazer as notas fora da lista consigo realizar o filtro, porém o nome, matricula, cpf se repetem. Agora desta forma que está o select não consegui realizar o filtro.

```cs
var query = from aluno in contexto.Aluno
            join nota in contexto.Nota  on aluno.Id equals nota.AlunoId
            where (nota.Nota < 7)
            select new { aluno.Nome, aluno.Matricula, aluno.Cpf, **s.Notas** }
```

Existe alguma forma?

Answer (score 0):

Lembrando que, dentro da sua model, você precisa ter uma propriedade de uma lista para este seu objeto (Nota), algo como:

```
public List<Nota> Notas { get; set; }
```

Tente assim:

```
var query = (from aluno in contexto.Aluno
            join nota in contexto.Nota on aluno.Id equals nota.AlunoId
            where (nota.Nota < 7)
            select new { aluno, nota }).ToList();

return query.Select(x=>x.aluno);
```